# anker keyboard escape key

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

My imac bluetooth keyboard had some keys broken so I bought an anker keyboard.

It's the one mentioned in this review:

http://ziacomputers.wordpress.com/2013/03/14/anker-bluetooth-keyboard-reveiew/

My problem with it is the same as the problem #1 in the review, the keyboard doesn't have a escape key.

The place where esc should be is an empty box symbol which you can see in this image:

[image]

You have to press fn + box to escape. I'm trying to remap it with KeyRemap4MacBook but I can't figure out how. The review mentions that it should be possible. Any assistance is appreciated thanks.

Comment: I have a similar keyboard, and Fn+HomeIcon keys is indeed Escape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Err, that's an iOS keyboard... (and the key is a Home button)

I would say that your easiest bet would be use use PCKeyboardHack (or KeyRemap4MacBook) to use the caps key was escape. I use this on my mac, as caps is normally useless anyway.

#### How to Change

- Note that Escape's code is 53
- Locate "Change Caps Lock", double click the key-code there, and to edit to 53

[image: PCKeyboardHack Screen Shot]

Comment: thanks i'm trying to figure out the remapping. Is this correct: http://cl.ly/image/1Z0a3P182a1t It's not working?

Comment: @Harry (I'm assuming you are taking the caps route) Note that escape's code is `53`, then scroll up and to where you should see "Change Caps Lock" and double click the key code there to edit to `53`

Answer (score 5):

The <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd> key combination works as <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Comment: I just wanted to add that the fn + home key does NOT function as ESC. I have a white version of this keyboard (or quite similar one, certainly same manufacturer).

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't.

Comment: It does work if it is paired to an iOS device..

Answer (score 2):

[iOSKeyboardEscapeKeyEnabler](https://github.com/dnicolson/iOSKeyboardEscapeKeyEnabler) will enable the home button on the keyboard to function as an escape key.

For some reason [Karibiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) is unable to read the key, possibly due to it being part of the "Consumer" page and not the "Generic Desktop" page.

Comment: This solution worked for me in the end! I had to disable the SHA check for `brew install` but it worked!